How can I assign the correct a11y focus direction for TalkBack
I have a vertical recycler view that stores horizontal recycler views (using GridLayout doesn't fit my solution), and most of the time only one horizontal recycler view is rendered to the user, and in order for him to switch to the next one, in the onKeyDown method I catch events pressed on DPAD (Android TV app) and control the focus behavior.
But when I turn on talkback, then the events of the click on the remote control do not go to DPAD Handler, but go directly to AccessibilityService and this means that my application will not receive events in onKeyDown/onKeyUp, and the control of the focus completely goes to AccessibilityService, and he in turn sees only one horizontal recycler view available on the screen and can not switch to another horizontal recycler view.
I tried to solve the problem via AccessibilityTraversalAfter/AccessibilityTraversalBefore, but it didn't help, because this solution is suitable only for touch devices, and for DPAD controls there is not only After/Before (Left/Right), but also Up/Down
I also tried tracking events in onInitializeAccessibilityEvent, but I couldn't find out where the user pressed on the remote control.
